# JNDI properties (java.naming.factory.initial & java.naming.provider.url) not getting set through Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, properties, jms, jndi

I have configured the following `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:///opt/myproject/jndi.properties" />
</bean>
```

And my JNDI template bean looks like

```
<bean id="myJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${factory}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${url}</prop>
        <props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

jndi.properties file has two keys defined.

```
factory=org.webmethods.jms.naming.WmJmsNamingCtxFactory
url=wmjmsnaming://MY_BROKER@abc.com:7001
```

When i deploy this on weblogic and start the application, i see the following trace

```
nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: ${factory} [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundExcep
tion: ${factory}]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
```

Spring isn't replacing ${factory} witht he value from the properties file but considers ${factory} as the value and thus shows a class not found exception.
If i hardcode the factory class name and the url, it works fine.
I am not sure whats missing here as i am not able to figure out whats really the issue.

Appreciate any help or pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use springs PropertiesFactoryBean like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="file:///opt/myproject/jndi.properties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found another simpler approach that doesn't need an extra class. i used `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean` to load the jndi.properties

The jndiTemplate bean looks something like this.

```
<bean id="myJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
             <property name="location" value="file:///opt/myproject/jndi.properties" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround solution which did work for me. Created my own JndiTemplate and read the jndi.properties file explicitly from the server. The custom class looks something like this

```
public class MyJndiTemplate extends JndiTemplate {

    @Override
    protected Context createInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Properties jndiProperties =  new Properties();
        final File file = new File("/opt/myproject/jndi.properties");
        try {
            jndiProperties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
    }
}
```

and then use this class in the spring context xml like this

```
<bean id="myJndiTemplate" class="com.MyJndiTemplate">
```

Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue.